# Correct syntax for retrieving custom field in CPT

Tags: custom-field

I don't understand when to use $post->ID or $post->post->ID with CPTs. I have :

```
$event = get_post( $event_id );
$event_pre_register = get_post_meta($event->post->ID, "Event Pre-register deadline", true);
```

Or is it : get_post_meta($event->ID ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the CPT's ID in the `$event_id` variable you plug into the `get_post()` call - why would you not simply just (re)use that for the first parameter of `get_post_meta()` ?

That aside, [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) returns a post object (instance of WP_Post), which you choose to assign to `$event`. Hence `$event` now has a public property `$ID`, which can be accessed by `$event->ID`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reuse `$event_id` here. `$event->ID` should be fine too.

Inspect your variables with a little helper like this:

```
print '<pre>$event = '
    . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $event, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE )
    . "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: +1 for the inspection snippet. Simple, but anyhoo, I usually dump shit with a straight `var_dump` - fine for a single float or the like, but this makes large objects or nested associative arrays so much more readable. Man, I dig "stealing" your code. ;)